# Numba - cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

Tags: python, numba

I could not find how to do this. Consider this dict:

```
this_size = numba.typed.Dict.empty(key_type=numba.types.float64, value_type=numba.types.float64)
```

I'm in `@numba.jit(nopython = True)`. I try to sum the values of this dict. But I get:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'sum': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

File "trial.py", line 163:
def strat_1(bid_price, ask_price, deal_size, deal_price, posture, post_update, is_out, num_ticks, tick_size, point_value):
    <source elided>
                BBB[i] = sum(this_size.values())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** `sum` is now supported as of Numba version 0.54! ([release notes](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/release-notes.html#version-0-54-0-19-august-2021), [PR](https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/6869))

---

Looks like `sum` isn't on the list of [supported built-in functions](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pysupported.html#built-in-functions) (as of Numba version 0.51.2). Right now, Numba supports a growing but still fairly limited subset of vanilla Python and NumPy.

Numba does support `np.sum`, although I wasn't able to convince it to take your dictionary's values (it might work with a bit more tinkering). The only way I got it to compile was by falling back a vanilla for loop:

```py
import numba
import numpy as np

this_size = numba.typed.Dict.empty(key_type=numba.types.float64, value_type=numba.types.float64)

@numba.njit
def my_sum(d):
  total = 0.0
  for val in d.values():
    total += val
  return total

print(my_sum(this_size))
```